# Check if variant is null in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am passing a variant as parameter into a function

For simplicity I have put up this sample functions to explain my situation

```
Public Function test()
Dim arr() As String
testing (arr)
End Function

Public Function testing(ar As Variant)
If ar = Empty Then
    MsgBox ("Hello")
End If
End Function
```

Sometimes the `FilesDetails` will be `null`, during that time the function is returning "`For loop not initialized`" error

How can I check if the variant is null?

I tried `UBound(FilesDetails), FilesDetails.Count,IsNull(FilesDetails)` but no luck

Comment: If FilesDetails is null, then this function should work. If it has 'no data' in other ways (empty string, empty array...) then IsNull won't do the trick. In that case, please be clear what kind of 'empty' is it.

Comment: it is a string
I have declared it as Dim FIlesDetails() as string

Comment: Did you tried `If Not FilesDetails Is Nothing Then` and the For loop within the If block? You might need `On Error Resume Next` below the Function.

Comment: it says object required

Comment: isNull(v) worked for me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved it by using the below method

```
Public Function test()
Dim Arr(1) As String
Arr(0) = "d"
Dim x As Boolean
x = IsArrayAllocated(Arr)
End Function


Function IsArrayAllocated(Arr As Variant) As Boolean
        On Error Resume Next
        IsArrayAllocated = IsArray(Arr) And _
                           Not IsError(LBound(Arr, 1)) And _
                           LBound(Arr, 1) <= UBound(Arr, 1)
End Function
```

The isArrayAllocated function returns true if its not null

Answer (score 6):

Try this :-)

```
Dim var As Variant

If var = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Variant data is Empty"
End If
```

or

```
If IsEmpty(var) Then
   MsgBox "Variant data is Empty"
End If
```

Comment: It says "type mismatch" 
Actually i have declared the variable as string array and passing it

Answer (score 2):

I would use IsNull function to check.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Public Function test()
   Dim arr() As String
   testing (arr)
End Function

Public Function testing(ar As Variant)
 If arr = "" Then
      MsgBox ("Hello")
    End If
End Function
```